# Datenum function is slow. What can I do?

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm trying to convert a character vector (200,000 rows) into Matlab serial numbers.
The format is `'01/07/2015 00:00:59'`.

This takes an incredibly long time, and online I can only find tips for solving this in Matlab. Any ideas how I can improve this?

Comment: Your input is probably a cell array of strings? How do you call datenum, do you pass the format?

Comment: What are the Matlab tips that solve it online? Are you sure they don't just work in Octave too?

Comment: The tips where to use .mex files from matlab which aren't available in octave. My input is a string array, but I converted it to a char matrix. Does that make a difference?

Comment: @BallzofFury the tip said to look inside the code for `datenum` and extract the bit that gets called for your specific string format, then just use that code. In Matlab it's calling a mex function, but whatever Octave calls should still be faster. Can you add a breakpoint to `datenum`? The idea is to skip out on all the processing `datenum` does trying to figure out how to convert for your specific format

Comment: I decided to write my own script since I do have a standard date format. Works much better, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`datenum(datevector)`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html#inputarg_DateVector) type of input for `datenum`.

It is much faster than the string parsing. I frequently use this trick whenever I have to import long date/time data (which is nearly everyday).

It consists in sending a `mx6` (or `mx3`) matrix, containing values representing `[yy mm dd HH MM SS]`. The matrix should be of type `double`.

It means instead of letting Matlab/Octave do the parsing, you read all the numbers in the string with your favourite way (`textscan`, `fscanf`, `sscanf`, ...), then you send numbers to `datenum` instead of string.

In the example below I generated a long array (86401x19) of date string as sample data:

```
>> strDate(1:5,:)
ans =
31/07/2015 15:10:13
31/07/2015 15:10:14
31/07/2015 15:10:15
31/07/2015 15:10:16
31/07/2015 15:10:17
```

To convert that to datenum faster than by the conventional way, I use:

```
strDate = [strDate repmat(' ',size(strDate,1),1)] ; %// add a whitespace at the end of each line
M = textscan( strDate.' , '%f/%f/%f %f:%f:%f'  ) ;  %'// read each value independently
M = cell2mat(M) ;                                   %// convert to matrix
M = M(:,[3 2 1 4 5 6]) ;                            %// reorder columns

dt = datenum(M ) ;                                  %// convert to serial date
```

---

This should bring speed up in Matlab but I am pretty sure it should improve things in Octave too. To quantify that at least on Matlab, here's a quick benchmark:

```
function test_datenum

d0 = now ;
d = (d0:1/3600/24:d0+1).' ; %// 1 day worth of date (one per second)

strDate = datestr(d,'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS') ; %'// generate the string array

fprintf('Time with automatic date parsing: %f\n' , timeit(@(x) datenum_auto(strDate)) )
fprintf('Time with customized date parsing: %f\n', timeit(@(x) datenum_preparsed(strDate)) )


function dt = datenum_auto(strDate)
    dt = datenum(strDate,'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS') ;       %// let Matlab/Octave do the parsing


function dt = datenum_preparsed(strDate)
    strDate = [strDate repmat(' ',size(strDate,1),1)] ; %// add a whitespace at the end of each line
    M = textscan( strDate.' , '%f/%f/%f %f:%f:%f'  ) ;  %'// read each value independently
    M = cell2mat(M) ;                                   %// convert to matrix

    M = M(:,[3 2 1 4 5 6]) ;                            %// reorder columns

    dt = datenum(M ) ;                                  %// convert to serial date
```

On my machine, it yields:

```
>> test_datenum
Time with automatic date parsing: 0.614698
Time with customized date parsing: 0.073633
```

---

Of course you could also compact the code in a couple of lines:

```
M = cell2mat(textscan([strDate repmat(' ',size(strDate,1),1)].','%f/%f/%f %f:%f:%f'))) ;
dt = datenum( M(:,[3 2 1 4 5 6]) ) ;
```

But I tested it and the improvement is so marginal that it is not really worth the loss of readability.